# how to display product detail description on product listing page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to show a detailed product description after a short description on the product listing page.

I'm doing this

```
<?
echo $_product->getDescription();
?>
```

but nothing shows up.

I also tried this

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getProductId())->getDescription();
```

but to no success.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try setting product attribute for descrption field "Used in Product Listing" to "YES".
That will solve your problem and avoid redundant model load

Answer (score 18):

The correct code is:

```
<?php

$my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

echo $my_product->getDescription();

?>
```

Comment: tnx for resolving ma issue :)

Comment: Can't use this method with additional attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`$_product->getProductId()` is not the function call you want, it is `$_product->getId()` :)

I advice you to take a look at the template in .../template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml. That template prints the description for the product view page, so you'll want a similar thing on the list page.

Answer (score 1):

for 1.6.2 it is:

path:

```
<?php

    $my_product =
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());

    echo $my_product->getDescription();

?>
```

Comment: Works for me with v1.9.2.2. For short description: __echo $my_product->getShortDescription();__

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have used this. It's working on magento 1.7

```
<?php echo $_product->_data['short_description']; ?>
```

Comment: That would be the short description, not the detailed description, though, right?

Answer (score 0):

This works in 1.7.0.2

`<div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>`

Comment: This only gets the short description