# How can I get custom Magento attributes in list.phtml?

Tags: php, magento

How can I get custom attributes in the Magento (version 1.4) category list of products (in `list.phtml`)?

I am trying to edit `catalog.xml` by adding

```
<action method="addAttribute"><code>format</code></action>
```

and in `list.phtml`

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('format'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_product->getFormat(); ?>
```

But it doesn't work. How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display product detail description on product listing page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027532/how-to-display-product-detail-description-on-product-listing-page)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, just place this code to where you need in list.phtml or view.phtml file.

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('unit');
if ($attribute){
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load attributes via `$_product->getAttributes()`

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.html#getAttributes